# putting html directly inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Is it possible to put html directly inside iframe in my html template? Is something like this valid?

```
<iframe>
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: I believe `srcdoc` attribute supports that, but its only supported in Chrome as far as I remember. So its not useful at all.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you have to put a link into an iframe to work. That means you need to make another HTML file and make `<iframe src="pagename.html"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

This only works on browsers that don't support the iframe element. Any decent browser will recognize it as an iframe and disblay a blank square instead.